# Modify query to exclude certain ids and certain parents and its corresponding children

Tags: wp-query, admin, query-posts, pre-get-posts

I'm trying to modify an admin `query` where I need to exclude a few pages based on two conditions:

1. Exclude based on certain titles
2. Exclude based on certain pages, including its children pages

To understand what I need to accomplish, the idea is the following. I have these pages:

> - PageA
> - PageB
> - Parent1
>
>   - Child1
>   - Child2
> - Parent2
>
>   - Child3
>   - Child4
> - Parent3
>
>   - Child5
>   - Child6
> - PageY
> - PageZ

Now, my actual code allows me to exclude "PageB" and "PageZ" based on its title. What I'm trying to do is to exclude "Parent1" and "Parent3" **and its corresponding children**.

The code I'm running now is this one:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'filter_dummy_pages');
function filter_dummy_pages($query) {
  if (function_exists('get_current_screen')) {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if (is_admin() and !current_user_can('manage_options') and $screen->post_type == 'page') {
      $query->set('post__not_in', get_dummy_pages());
    }
  }
}

function get_dummy_pages() {
  $result = array();
  $pages_query = array(
    'PageB',
    'PageZ'
  );

  foreach ($pages_query as $page) {
    $result[] = get_page_by_title($page)->ID;
  }

  return $result;
}
```

I have tried to make a `WP_Query` inside `get_dummy_pages()`, but I get a white page, so I assume the issue is related to attepmt a `query` inside an actual `query`.

I have also tried poking the `post_parent`, `post_parent__in` and `post_parent__not_in` options, but I get to exclude way more pages than I want.

Which options should I consider for this use case?

Comment: Re the white page, please turn on WP_DEBUG - it'll tell you what you're doing wrong and will make it a heck of a lot easier to debug :)

Comment: I have `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG` activated, but now I activated `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY` and got what seems to be an infinite loop when trying to run a `WP_Query` in the `get_dummy_pages` function.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it is possible to run a `WP_Query` inside a `pre_get_posts` action keeping in mind two simple principles:

1. `pre_get_posts` action will alter **every query** that you make, so you need to contain its action specifying which queries you need to alter. In this case, this containment is done with this line:

   ```
   if (
     is_admin()
     and !current_user_can('manage_options')
     and $screen->post_type == 'page'
   ) {
     ...
   }
   ```

   This means that I'm altering only the query that happens when you load `edit.php?post_type=page` in Administration Panel.
2. Because of the former, `pre_get_posts` will alter the main query of the page, which is "*query all pages*". My question attempted to run a `WP_Query` inside an action that alters every query, so this action was also altering my "sub-queries". So, as the first principle tells us, we need to contain the action to **act only on the main query**, because if we don't contain it, we'll get an infinite loop. So, our "containment" line needs to know if what we're altering is actually the main query:

   ```
   if (
     is_admin()
     and !current_user_can('manage_options')
     and $screen->post_type == 'page'
     and $query->is_main_query()  // This contains only the main query
   ) {
     ...
   }
   ```

   So now we can run whatever `WP_Query` we want in the `get_dummy_pages()` function.